Is what I wrote one pattern or two patterns?
Should sales for the three companies all increased and Company X had the highest sales figure be viewed as one pattern or two patterns? I don't know if I should use pattern or patterns. I somehow feel it is one pattern with with, and two patterns with and.

Sales for the three companies all increased with Company X having the highest sales figure compared to the
other three. This pattern is expected to continue into the future.


Sales for the three companies all increased and Company X had the highest sales figure compared to the other
three. These patterns are expected to continue into the future.


I would say "trend" but I don't know what X stands for, and that can make a difference.

Side note: It would be compared to the other two, but there's no need to say "compared to the other..."  because that comparison is implicit in the phrase  the highest.

Your first passage describes a single relationship—the one between the increase of X and those of the other three—and the behavior of that relationship over time. Thus pattern should be singular.
In your second, it’s somewhat ambiguous whether the conjuncts are meant as separate patterns. If yes, then I’d suggest beginning with something like We noticed two patterns:
I’d note further (and beyond the original question) that your construction with fastest is somewhat awkward. Better would be

They all increased, with Company X’s growth being the fastest of the four. This pattern…


Sorry, I edited my question because someone commented they don't know what X stands for.

Here’s a fun micro fact for you. In mathematical practice, variables are always set in italics. Thus I choose to do that even in nontechnical text when the symbol is more of a one-letter name for a mystery entity than literally a mathematical variable.
